# I can not create a MIDI file twice, using JFugue on Android

Tags: java, android, midi, jfugue

I am using [JFugue for Android](https://github.com/kshoji/JFugue-for-Android) and I have been able to generate Midi files, which subsequently reproduce using MediaPlayer. My code is as follows:

My problem is that I can only create the MIDI file the first time I pressed the Play button on the UI. The second time I press Play, the method

```
MidiFileManager.savePatternToMidi (. Rhythm.getPattern () setTempo (tempo) REPEAT (repeat), file),
```

remains frozen and the program is no longer responding.

I can no longer think of any idea how to fix the problem.

My code is as follows:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.midicreator.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
        android:onClick="play" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ritmos_spinner"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.midicreator;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


import org.jfugue.midi.MidiFileManager;
import org.jfugue.player.Player;
import org.jfugue.rhythm.Rhythm;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Rhythm rhythm;
    private File file;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private Ritmos ritmos;
    private String music;
    private int tempo, repeat;
    int i = 1;

    Spinner ritmos_spinner;
    String[] ritmos_list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerRitmosAdapter;


    public static Map<Character, String> Instruments = new HashMap<Character, String>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        {
            put('x', "[LO_BONGO]i");
            put('o', "[BASS_DRUM]i");
            put('.', "Ri");
        }};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rhythm = new Rhythm(Instruments);

        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Ritmos", this.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ritmos = new Ritmos(sharedPref);

        file = new File(this.getFilesDir(),"OutputMidi.mid");

        //////////
        // Botones
        //////////

        ritmos_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ritmos_spinner);
        ritmos_list = ritmos.getRitmos().keySet().toArray(new String[ritmos.getRitmos().keySet().size()]);
        spinnerRitmosAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ritmos_list);
        spinnerRitmosAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ritmos_spinner.setAdapter(spinnerRitmosAdapter);

        file = new File(this.getFilesDir(),"OutputMidi.mid");

    }


    public void play(View view){

        music = ritmos.getRitmo(ritmos_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        tempo = 120;
        repeat = 1;

        rhythm.addLayer(music);

        try {
            MidiFileManager.savePatternToMidi(rhythm.getPattern().setTempo(tempo).repeat(repeat),file);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(file));

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Ritmos.java

```
package com.example.android.midicreator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.Map;

import static android.provider.Settings.Global.getString;


public class Ritmos {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;


    // Constructor
    public Ritmos(SharedPreferences sharedPref){
        this.sharedPref = sharedPref;
        FirstInit();
    }

    private void FirstInit(){
        if(sharedPref.getString("INI","Y").compareTo("Y") == 0){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            editor.putString("INI","N");
            editor.putString("Alegría", "xxx.o.x.x.o.xxo.xxo.x.o.");
            editor.putString("Bulería", "x.x.o.x.x.o.xxo.xxo.x.o.");
            editor.putString("Soleá", ".xx.o..xx.o..xo..xo.x.o.");
            editor.putString("Sevillanas", "x.x.o.x.x.o.");
            editor.putString("Tangos", "xxx.x...");

            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    public boolean setRitmo(String name, String ritmo){

        if(validateRitmo(ritmo)){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(name, ritmo.toLowerCase());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    private boolean validateRitmo(String ritmo){

        boolean validate = false;

        for(char c : ritmo.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
            if(c != 'x' || c != 'o' || c != '.'){
                break;
            }

            validate = true;
        }

        return validate;
    }

    public Map<String, ?> getRitmos(){
        Map<String, ?> ritmos = sharedPref.getAll();
        ritmos.remove("INI");

        return ritmos;
    }

    public String getRitmo(String name){
        return sharedPref.getString(name,"xox");
    }

}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.midicreator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android/raw/master/javax.sound.midi/repository'}
    maven { url 'https://github.com/kshoji/JFugue-for-Android/raw/master/jfugue-android/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'jp.kshoji:javax-sound-midi:0.0.3:@aar'
    compile 'jp.kshoji:jfugue-android:5.0.1.201503:@aar'
}
```